# Does R have NCSS -style "Descriptive statistics" or other reports?

Tags: r, statistics

NCSS bundles with all kind of nice reports that speed up monotone analysis enormously. Is there any package in R that copycats NCSS -style reporting? You can find NCSS [here](http://ncss.com/ncss.html). I believe that R has all necessary tools to create NCSS -style reports but I have never found anything in the degree of NCSS reports. Have you?

With the term `reports`, I can find the following packages in Cran. The results are extremely new so no idea about them.

- R.rsp    Dynamic generation of scientific reports
- batade   HTML reports and so on

and more with the term `report`:

- brew Templating Framework for Report Generation
- dmRTools Data Management Reporting Tool Version 1.0.1
- HTMLUtils    Facilitates automated HTML report creation
- knitr    A general-purpose package for dynamic report generation in R
- metrumrg Pharmacometric tools for data preparation, modeling, simulation, and reporting
- MIfuns   Pharmacometric tools for data preparation, modeling, simulation, and reporting
- rapport  A report templating system
  eportr A general message and error reporting system
- reporttools  Generate LaTeX tables of descriptive statistics

With the term `Descriptive statistics`, I find:

- descr    Descriptive statistics
- prettyR  Pretty descriptive stats
- reporttools  Generate LaTeX tables of descriptive statistics

I fast skim-read the publication dates and all of the packages are pretty young, apparently many pioneers working on this. Now any of them close to NCSS -reports?

Comment: Which features are you looking for?
If you want nice-looking reports,
you can look at 
[Sweave](http://www.statistik.lmu.de/~leisch/Sweave/)
(or perhaps [odfWeave](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/odfWeave/index.html), if you are not familiar with LaTeX)
or, more generally, the 
[reproducible research task view](http://cran.fyxm.net/web/views/ReproducibleResearch.html).
If you want nice-looking summary statistics, in a PDF file,
you can use `latex(describe(myDataFrame))`, from the 
[`Hmisc`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hmisc/index.html) package.

Comment: @VincentZoonekynd: wow that is interesting, is there some easy-to-get trial data to test this kind of tools? I am looking for general tools like that.

Comment: @hhh R has a variety of built-in datasets.  For data frames, you can use `mtcars` or `quakes`, for example.  See also `?datasets`

Comment: What you mentioned are some general templating packages, which means you need to fill your own code in them. I do not think it is terribly hard to do the job of enumerating all common statistical procedures and writing your own templates; it is mostly labor work. But as a statistician growing with R, I do not like these tedious templates. In most cases, I need to play with my data for a while to decide how to write my report; I feel predefined procedures tie my hands.

Comment: OMG the front page for NCSS has a dynamite plot with the y-axis starting at 100. I wouldn't trust them based solely on that.

Comment: I'm more extreme: I do not trust dynamite plots at all :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The other keyword that you could use is `describe`. There are several packages with different versions of a `describe` function, The one I use is the `rms/Hmisc` bundle. You might find further value in looking at Hmisc's `describe.formula` whose results can be passed to Hmisc::latex. This naturally requires that you have a LaTeX installation.

One way of judging a package's degree of acceptance is to look at how many other packages depend upon it or add functionality. In that arena `Sweave` is the hands down leader. (I thought Vincent should have written his response as an answer. I started writing this without reading his comment very thoughly.)

I doubt that you will find exactly what you describe. The philosophy underlying R is different than the design principles that resulted in NCSS. R developers wanted maximal flexibility while NCSS developers make many assumptions about their users, mainly that the developers know more than the users regarding what sorts of reports should be created and further that they are providing a stand-alone solution. NCSS started out as a modular microcomputer stats system, but has apparently evolved into a much more integrated package driven by lots of dialog boxes.  R was developed by statisticians for statisticians. They expected these other statisticians would know how to build what they wanted from a set of basic tools, and the goal was economy of output and the capacity to add precisely what was needed. They expected the results to be exported to other programs for editing and report writing. You are not likely to find very many people who have mastered R who want to go back to re-create a system that forces them (or others) into a severely-constrained category of naive-user.  Consider the difference between Excel and C or between LaTeX and MS-Word.

Comment: I pretty much agree with you except the second paragraph. It is a nightmare to develop packages based on Sweave, so I cannot tell where Sweave is leading these packages to.

Comment: @Yihui: I agree that Sweave poses a significant set of barriers for adoption, even by the user, but are you disagreeing with whether it _is_ or whether it _should_be_ the most widely used reporting mechanism?

Comment: I mean _should be_. I cannot deny it _is_ most widely used :) But if you mean _mechanism_, I do not disagree at all. I strongly recommend working with this mechanism.